# Unfolding a Billiard Trajectory

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

The following image is from page 1019 of http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~lanneau/references/masur_tabachnikov_chap13.pdf[image]

From what I understand about unfolding billiards we are representing the path of a billiard in the original quadrilateral with a line of constant slope (the original slope of the billiard). In the third polygon (from the left) the billiard is hitting a side and looks as if its next move will be to hit the line with slope one. However, in the next polygon the billiard is headed back into the vertical side. Isn't this path supposed to reflect the path of the billiard in the original quadrilateral?

Is there a nice way to determine how to reflect the polygon at any step of the unfolding?

Comment: I agree with you.  You should reflect the table in the side being hit.  The fourth one is flipped left-to-right from the way it should be.  The last one doesn't connect correctly to the next-to-last, either.

Comment: When I adjust the 4th polygon so that it does hit the short slanted side there doesn't seem to be a way to reflect the polygon after that.

Comment: Now reflect it in the short slanted side, which means the next one will point up.  The next hit is the long side in a vertical orientation, so the next polygon will have the long side vertical and on the left.  You can always keep going.  It is acceptable for the reflected polygon to overlay previous ones, but I haven't seen that happen here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explicate the general procedure @Ross described, I single it out once more:

*You need to reflect the table in the side being hit.*

Associated intuition is as if you're looking at the ball being reflected against a mirror (after the ball hits the mirror, you start looking at it through the mirror). This means that the third and fifth reflections in the included image are done wrong.

Once you get a bit of intuition for this kind of thing it will all make sense. You can experiment with a piece of paper and some simpler shapes (e.g. an equilateral triangle or a rectangle). Bonus of this is that it's actually fun to do :).