# Determining if two particles collide in a 2d container

Tags: vectors, computer-science, plane-geometry, angle, collision-detection

I'm trying to determine if two particles collide within a certain period of time in a 2D container. Given the positions and velocities of the particles, I know a formula to determine if there is a collision between them in a 2D plane would be:
$$t = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{v_{y_1} - v_{y_2}} = \frac{x_2 - x_1}{v_{x_1} - v_{x_2}}$$ Where if both equations are equal and greater than zero, there is a collision at time $t$.

This works in an infinite plane, but I'm not sure how to account for wall bounces when they are in a container. I tried considering the relative velocity, but that would assume the particle is travelling a direct path to its endpoint which doesn't work.

In my scenario, particles start at whole number coordinates and can only have integer value vectors for x and y. If they collide at all within a certain time, they both disappear, so there's no need to account for collision physics. Consider the points $(2,1)$ and $(3,0)$ with velocities in units/$s$ $(2,2)$ and $(4,4)$ respectively and a wall at $x = 4$. There should be a collision at $t=0.5s$.

I will also have to consider three particles and multiple collisions later. In this case I think I would just resolve the one with the lowest $t$ first, remove those particles and then reevaluate.

Comment: Do you happen to know the [unfolding technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/364779/305862) ?

Comment: I have heard of it, but I'm not sure how I would apply it in this scenario. Without it, the particle that hits the wall will reverse it's vector perpendicular to the wall. With the unfolding technique, wouldn't the opposite be true? Where particles that don't hit having to reverse their vector?